# How to add selected indexes of tableview sections to an array

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a `tableView` with `section headers` and I want to append a certain user input to multiple selected `headers`. I have created the `section headers` and am able to change the image on the `section header` to show that it is selected but I want to create an `array` of those selected.

Here is my code for the `section header`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let userModel = Data.userModels[section]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nameCell") as! NameHeaderTableViewCell

    cell.setup(model: userModel)
    cell.checkMarkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.enable(on: false)
    if isUserEditing == true {
        cell.enable(on: true)
    }
    return cell.contentView
}
```

Here is where I change the `section image` when a user taps the section:

```
    @objc func handleTap(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

}
```

When the user clicks the save `button`, I want the user input to be appended to those cells where the `section header` is selected. Here is that code:

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
    //VALIDATION
    guard  mealItemTextField.text != "", let item = mealItemTextField.text else {
        mealItemTextField.placeholder = "please enter an item"
        mealItemTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        mealItemTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        return
    }
    guard  priceTextField.text != "", let price = Double(priceTextField.text!) else {
        priceTextField.placeholder = "please enter a price"
        priceTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        priceTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        return
    }
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Currently I am stuck on how to access all of the `indexes` of the `sections` that are selected(i.e. the ones that have a state of selected) Here are some screenshots to help visualize the program:
[image]
[image]

**P.S.** Not sure if this is helpful but I populate the data with an `array` of `structs`. Here is that code:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return Data.userModels.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if Data.userModels[section].isExpandable {
            return Data.userModels[section].itemModels.count
        } else {
            return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = Data.itemModels[indexPath.row].itemName
    return cell!
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your checkmarks are merely a visual feature of the header. When the user taps on a checkmark, you're merely toggling its selected state:

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

That's not going to work. You need to be keeping track of this information at all times in a part of your data model that deals with the section headers. That way, when the Save button is clicked, the information is sitting there in the data model waiting for you. Your `handleTap` needs to work out what section this is the header of and reflect the info off into the model. The data model is the source of truth, not some view in the interface. (I am surprised that you are not already having trouble with this when you scroll your table view.)

Another problem with your code is this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nameCell") as! NameHeaderTableViewCell
```

You can't use a UITableViewCell as a reusable section header view. You need to be using a UITableViewHeaderFooterView here.

Comment: I feel like the data model would be fine if I could just access the correct index. The names are from an array of names and I simply want to append the food item and price to the selected names.

Comment: Right, well you have to have a way of getting from the header view to the section of which it is the header.